# android developer - app download count not updating since 31 December, 2013

Tags: android

I have uploaded a new app "Bangla Typing" on Google play store in 31 December, 2013. Today is 2nd January. My apps got 28 reviews, but download count is still showing 0+

Here's the link to my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bdrulez.banglatyping

In my Google play developer console... It's showing total download 545. Active users 415.

Comment: I won't DownVote, but this question does not belong here, you're better off searching Google for common posts on this issue. Good luck!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of the Google Play Store and not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i upload my app on Google Play i have the same issue.Actually there is not any problem.There is a delay.Wait for 1-2 days more it will be there :)

Comment: i didn't get update counter.i have checked backend database side,there is 4000 user register my app.but in play store,counter is not being update.its display only 10-50 download.please give me some trick to check and update counter in play store

Comment: that's weird.Why dont you contact Google about the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay until the number gets updated, it can be back by 1-2 days